# Why can't I take the address of a return value?

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

I've split some code into two files, it was working before. In one file I have a function which has an out value parameter which is a pointer to a pointer.

I'm filling this parameter with a call to a getter and dereferencing it:

```
foo(&bar());
```

however I get an error saying ''&' requires an l-value'. I understand what this error means, but I thought I would be able to do this because it's a pointer and so does represent the original 'thing'.

Is it something to do with the fact that the actual pointers memory location could change, even though it would point to the right thing? but why did it work before when it was in the same file and not now?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you need an lvalue, i.e. something that can be assigned to. You can't assign to the return value of a function.

You need to do something like this:

```
temp = bar();
foo(&temp);
```

Comment: @spraff Hmm, references. Something tells me that this may be C code in fact.

Answer (score 2):

Using &, you aren't dereferencing, but referencing. To derefrence, use * instead: `foo(*(bar()));`.

And if you do want to *reference* it, put the result of `bar()` in a temporary variable:

```
x = bar();
foo(&x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `foo` takes a pointer-to-int, try:

```
foo((int[]){bar()});
```

Comment: +1 Very nice. Seems to work with a struct. Is this a gcc extension? (Can't test at the moment.)

Comment: It's C99 (compound literals).

Answer (score 0):

I guess `bar()` is:

```
type *bar () { return member_pointer; }
```

which returns the pointer `member_pointer` by value, hence not an l-vlaue.

If you want to modify the value `member_pointer` in `foo()`, you need:

```
type **bar () { return &member_pointer; }
```

Comment: so you have to create getters for pointers to pointers? I thought you could just use the getter to get the pointer, and then reference that with &. Why is it that you can't do that? It seems inelegant to have to create so many getters.

Comment: @SirYakalot: Only if you want to alter the pointer value in the owning class.